# Springboot passing ModelAndView from a controller to another

Tags: spring-boot

In Springboot 2.7 I have a simple controller that dinamically sets up a page using a static resource:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/controller-first", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView controller-first(  Locale locale,
                               HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response,
                               Model model)
{   
 dinamically manipulate model here...     
 return new ModelAndView("static_resource_here");
}
```

With this controller I have a form and submit that calls the second controller. The second controller should keep the ModelAndView from the first controller, modify the ModelAndView and send it to the user. Which is the best solution to implement such controller?

Comment: You don't as that goes through the web. It all seems quite convoluted what you are trying to achieve. Also isn't it a bit of a contradiction *dynamically set up a page with a static resource*?

Comment: the "static resource" is the template used from the first controller on which the modifications are applied

Comment: I still don't get it but you don't keep a `ModelAndView` between requests, you will need to repopulate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to maintain session in spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457461/how-to-maintain-session-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. In the second controller I added a RedirectAttributes, then in the body I write:

```
 //for each attribute changed
 attributes.addFlashAttribute("attribute_name", model.getAttribute("name"));
 //now redirect to the first controller
 return new ModelAndView("redirect:/controller-first");
```